# Bootstrap 4: Change # of Grid Columns in a Single Row

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is it possible to set $grid-columns for a single .row in Bootstrap 4? I've dug into the documentation, and have looked around here for answers, but nothing I try seems to have an effect.

I was thinking I could create a 10 or 5 column grid, just for those rows, and stick to the default 12 columns elsewhere in the the layout.

Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way, and there's a simpler solution.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. It's three rows of 5 boxes, with the box in the dead center having a width that is 3x the width of the other columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the auto columns, and some CSS for the custom width of 20%...

```
.col-20 {
    max-width: 20%;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Yuo6p37HEt

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col col-20">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col col-20">

    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to work that out!